# Ctrl+alt+shift+R for recording not working Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, bug-reporting, 20.10, desktop-recording

I tried to record but nothing happens on doing the keyboard shortcut. I changed the shortcut and tried again but nothing happened

Anyone else having this too?

Comment: custom shortcut using 'gnome-screenshot' -    ... see help for more options like fullscreen or windowed.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug in Ubuntu. See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1901391

You can find some background information on this issue here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3329

As workaround you could use an extra application, for example RecApp available on [flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.amikha1lov.RecApp).

Comment: You can click the recording button in the top right corner to stop the recording. I love this new feature, but the bug is so annoying.